# Using External Monitor. Want Mouse to move Up/Down, not Left/Right?

Tags: macos, display, system-settings

I've got an external monitor and want to be able to use the monitor above the laptop.

It seems I'm supposed to use *"Spaces"* to support an external monitor which I have done and I've set up two spaces for this. Unfortunately it seems that I'm only able to move between spaces by moving my mouse cursor from left to right instead of from top to bottom and vice versa. Given the layout of the monitors it is really unnatural to have to move from left to right in order to access monitors that are stacked.  I can easily do this on my Dell laptop running Windows but is there a way to do it with my Mac's OS X?  Stumped.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101104-182214.png))</sub>

Thanks in advance for the help.

-Mike

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't need to worry about Spaces for this.  What you need to do is go into:

System Preferences --> Displays --> Arrangement

Drag the icon representing your external monitor to the top of the icon representing your macbook monitor:

[image: vertical display arrangement]

You can also drag the bar representing your menubar/dock to whichever monitor you want to be your "main" display.

Comment: Perfect, awesome answer! I love StackExchange! But I do have a follow up question, I'll ask it on another question.

Comment: Here's the other question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/moving-menu-bar-to-external-monitor

Comment: @Mike: glad I could help, and thanks for the enthusiastic thanks :P

Comment: Dude you are a saint! I was having a similar problem, thanks

Comment: @Chori: no problem, glad it helped

Comment: Created an account just to upvote this. Thanks a lot!