# How do I move my menubar to an external monitor?

Tags: macos, display, system-settings, menu-bar

I just asked this question *([Using External Monitor and Spaces. Want Mouse to move Up/Down, not Left/Right?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3694/using-external-monitor-and-spaces-want-mouse-to-move-up-down-not-left-right/3695#3695))* and [@calavera](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/26/calavera) gave me a great answer, thanks!

But now I have another question. It seems that the menubar wants to stay with the laptop and doesn't seem to be possible to move to the external monitor. Am I beating a dead horse here or is it somehow possible to achieve the layout I'm looking for? See screenshot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/Color_LCD-20101104-190946.png))</sub>

Comment: As already suggested, click and drag the menubar :) It’s a movable object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try and drag the menubar icon you're pointing to in that screenshot to the other monitor.  It's kind of hard to grab with the mouse pointer but it should work if you can click/drag that white space rather than the blue space representing the monitor.

Comment: Dammit, I hate being a *"stupid user."* But I absolutely **love** having someone give me a solution so quickly when I'm stuck and think there's just no solution. So thank you again!

Comment: @Mike the funny thing is you took the time to take a sshot, open it with skitch and all that when your mousepointer was hovering over that at all times. It happens :)

Comment: @Mike: nothing stupid about that... it took me awhile to figure out that you could drag that stupid white bar as well.  And I must have been using Snow Leopard for 6 months before I noticed you could drag the monitors on top of each other instead of just left and right :P

Answer (score 7):

[SecondBar](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=79) is also an excellent free app that will add a second menu bar on the other monitor.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I wanted to remove the middle one, not add another but good to know for future reference.

Comment: Is SecondBar, or it's functionality, still available anywhere?